# Can you explain to me the statement of this problem?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $n$ a natural number and $A=(a_{ij})$, where $a_{ij}=\left(\begin{array}{c} i+j \\ i \end{array}\right)$, for $0 \leq i,j < n $. Prove that $A$ has an inverse matrix and that all the entries of $A^{-1}$ are integers.

What I don't understand is the definition of $a_{ij}$, I was thinking that it is just a column vector but that would mean that $A$ is a $(2n) \times n$ matrix, so how could it be invertible if it's not a square matrix?

Comment: From what you wrote, $i$ and $j$ both range over the cardinality $n$ set  $\{0,1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$. So that's indeed an $n\times n$ matrix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number $\dbinom{i+j}{j}$ is a **binomial coefficient**.

It is the number of ways to choose $j$ objects from $i+j$ objects. One expression for it is $\dfrac{(i+j)!}{i!j!}$.